# Disable enemy attacks in Factorio

Tags: factorio

Is it possible to enable "Enemies never attack first" option in an existing save game? Could I modify a specific file to achieve the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the console (open via the ` button) and enter this command:

```
/c game.player.surface.peaceful_mode = true
```

You will need to enter it twice (as the console text will inform you), and it will disable the achievements from that point onwards for the saved game.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this command to turn peaceful mode on:

`/c game.player.surface.peaceful_mode = true`

You can open the console by using the <kbd>`</kbd> key.

Peaceful mode will make it so enemies will not attack you unless you attack first. 
Checkout [the Wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Console#Enemy.2FEvolution) for more commands.  Note that this will disable achievements.